# Partial derivative of $f(x,y) = z$ with respect to $z$

Tags: partial-derivative

This is probably a really bad question with some major oversights, but I don't seem to see them right now.

If I define a function 
$$ z = f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$$
and took the partial derivative respect to $z$ of $z$ and $f(x,y)$ is it correct to say:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial z}{\partial z} &= \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial z}  \\
1 &= 2x\frac{\partial x}{\partial z} + 2y\frac{\partial y}{\partial z} \ ?
\end{align}

I tried Wolfram Alpha but it gave me this instead.

[image: Screenshot of Wolfram Alpha]

Following the chain rule I get the same answer.

Comment: Neither the question nor the accepted answer makes any sense.

Comment: Notation? Or just in general.

Comment: One only can take partial derivatives when a certain set of variables has been declared and agreed as independent. In the case at hand these are the variables $x$ and $y$. It is only allowed to take partial derivatives with respect to these two. You don't even know what kind of information the "partial derivative of whatever with respect to $z$" should convey.

Comment: Right, so I guess my question should have been is there a multivariable equivalent to single variable implicit differentiation. The YouTuber 3blue1one brown did something similar. 3 variables of which 2 are independent and 1 dependent. https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=%23&ved=2ahUKEwizk5mFgMXeAhUq1VkKHTu0B30Q8TUwAHoECAkQAw&usg=AOvVaw0VTJzWxrN8ZFOD4xbU2nov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woflram outputs this result because it assumes x and y don't depend on z, which means it finds that:

$\frac{\partial x}{\partial z} = 0, \frac{\partial y}{\partial z} = 0$

But yes, you can technically say:

$1=2x \frac{\partial x}{\partial z}+2y \frac{\partial y}{\partial z}$

Although it's rather meaningless. You're expecting the partials of x and y with respect to z to yield "something else", but x and y DO depend on z by:

$z=x^2 + y^2$

We can explicitly show it by:

$x=\sqrt{z-y^2}$ and $y=\sqrt{z-x^2}$

Then using the Chain Rule:

$\frac{\partial x}{\partial z} =\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{z-y^2}}(1-2y\frac{\partial y}{\partial z})=\frac{1}{2x}(1-2y\frac{\partial y}{\partial z})$ and $\frac{\partial y}{\partial z} =\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{z-x^2}}(1-2x\frac{\partial x}{\partial z})=\frac{1}{2y}(1-2x\frac{\partial x}{\partial z})$

Plugging them into each other:

$\frac{\partial x}{\partial z} =\frac{1}{2x}(1-2y(\frac{1}{2y}(1-2x\frac{\partial x}{\partial z})))=\frac{1}{2x}(2x\frac{\partial x}{\partial z})=\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}$

$\frac{\partial y}{\partial z} =\frac{1}{2y}(1-2x(\frac{1}{2x}(1-2y\frac{\partial y}{\partial z})))=\frac{1}{2y}(2y\frac{\partial y}{\partial z})=\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}$

And we come to a roundabout answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Would it be wrong though if I took the partial derivative of z respect to x and got this dz/dx = 2x + 2y (dy/dx) (assume d = partial sign) and said dy/dx is zero

Comment: Pardon me I havn't taken calc 3 in a while

Comment: If you know that y is not a function of x, then yes dy/dx would be 0, and then dz/dx=2x. But you would have to know if there was another relationship for y to get dy/dx=0.

Comment: Can't f(x,y) and x have a relationship with y. Like y = sqrt(z - y^2)?

Comment: To get the two square-root functions I wrote before, I just inverted z=x^2+y^2 for both x and y. But to get something like y=sqrt(z-y^2), you'd need to know that a relationship of the form z=2y^2 also exists. Is this for a homework problem?

Comment: No, I just wanted to review Calc 1,2,3

Comment: I made up that question. I'm trying to understand the divergence theorem but to do that I needed to learn normal vectors of a surface which lead me to gradients then to partial derivatives.

Comment: So for a surface z = f(x,y) to find the normal vector we define F(x,y,z) = f(x,y) - z. Knowing that the gradient is always orthogonal to the level curve 0 = f(x,y) - z, we take the gradient of F(x,y,z) and for (x,y,z) on the surface the grad(F(x,y,z) will be the normal vector at that point. However, taking the gradient threw me off since the f(x,y) = z I thought the partial of f(x,y) respect to z equaled the partial of z respect to z. Anyways I'll be posting another question on this.